# C#: How do I find out which process opened a file and how can I close it?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to delete a file selected by the user at his request but this file has already been opened by another process and I get the System.IO.IOException. At the beginning of the application, all files are called via SQLite and assigned to an ObservableCollection that simultaneously represents the ItemSource for a ListView. Now, for example, the images are displayed and I think that this process uses the files but the process is no longer terminated. How can I close this process to regain access to the files?

```
     // In Constructor
     if (!(Directory.Exists(pathString)))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            GetUris();
        }
      private async void GetUris()
      {
        var db = App.Db;
          //aus datenbank lesen
        if (db.GetAllItemsAsync().Result.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < db.GetAllItemsAsync().Result.Count; 
        i++)
            {
                int id = db.GetAllItemsAsync().Result[i].Id;
                ItemData data = db.GetItemAsync(id).Result;
                PlayList.Add(data);
                
            }
        } 
     }
     private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        var item = (ListView)sender;
        
        if (Mouse.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("Soll die Datei gelöscht werden ?", "Action", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (mbr == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                string file = (item.SelectedItem as ItemData).ImageSource;
                
                //Here i want to Delete the File in Folder
                
                DeleteItem((item.SelectedItem as ItemData).URI);
                PlayList.Remove(item.SelectedItem as ItemData);
               
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Closing the process that is locking the file is the user's responsibility, not yours.

Comment: Maybe I have expressed myself incorrectly, but I create a folder during the runtime in which all media selected by the user are stored and the string path is stored in the database to call up these media from the folder again. If the user now wants to delete a file from the list, it should also be removed from the folder.

Answer (score -2):

```
bool _quit = false;

Thread _thread = new Thread(queue);
void StartThread() {
    _thread.Start();
}

void KillThread() {
    _quit = true;
}
```

you can set a flag true or false for a thread process.